Как выполнить команду в хроме в заданное время?
Подскажите,как заставить код сверять время с удаленным сервером(например майкрософт). Мне нужно выполнить нажатие кнопки в окне браузера в заданное время, например в 2:10:05 UTC .
Нашел подходящий код,но он отталкивается от времени которое передает браузер
var start_hour = 18;

function doSomething(){
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("el-button el-button--primary _9Nk+tQ");
elems[0].click();
}

var _inter = setInterval(function(){
    // Если время не пришло - прерываемся
    if(new Date().getHours() < 18)return;
    
    // Прерываем таймер
    clearInterval(_inter);

    // Стартуеем!
    doSomething();
}, 300);// Проверяем трижды на секунду.


setTimeout(doSomething, new Date('2024-07-03T02:10:05').getTime() - Date.now()) ?

Спасибо Вам!. Но я всю ночь пытался интегрировать это в мой скрипт, не решаясь спросить и теперь сдаюсь, надеясь на помощь

Во-первых, не надо менять вопрос на полностью другой, новый вопрос задавайте в новом вопросе. Во-вторых, новый вопрос всё равно непонятен
